# Module Federation: app crashes when trying to load dynamic remotes for the first time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We have the scenario where a React app exposes two different components which are later dynamically loaded by the host application using module federation. We are using [dynamic remotes](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#dynamic-remote-containers), and so far, the setup looks almost exactly the same as in [this module federation example on GitHub.](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/advanced-api/dynamic-remotes/app1/src/App.js) with the exception of it being ported to TS.

This works fine 99% of the time, but whenever the remote is re-deployed, the host application refreshes and, consequently, tries to load the remotes again, the entire App (including the host) will go blank and the only error we are seeing in the console is...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined`

...and I understand that the `default` not being defined stems from the following line:

`await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default);`

After another refresh, it all goes back to normal and the remote components are rendered as intended. Until the next time we redeploy.

Any suggestions as to how we could go about debugging it or potential causes would be much appreciated.

We tried the following things:

- in `ModuleFederationPlugin` set React dependency to `singleton` and/or `eager`
- removed LazyLoading from the FederatedComponent

Answer (score 0):

you should try this for your code:

```js
const Player = React.lazy(
// @ts-ignore
    () => import('videoPlayer/VideoPlayer') as Promise<{ default: any }>,
);

function VideoPlayer(props: Params) {
    return (
            <React.Suspense fallback={<VideoPlayerLoading/>}>
                <Player {...props}/>
            </React.Suspense>
    );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).